# Apply central limit theorem to solve probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I am asking to use central limit theorem to solve this quesion.
In an election between two candidates, A and B, one million individuals cast their vote.  Among these, 2000 know candidate A from her election campaign and vote unanimously for her. The remaining 998000 voters are undecided and make their decision independently of each other by flipping a fair coin.  Approximate the probability pA that candidate A wins up to 3 significant figures.

I got my mean = np = (1000000-2000)  * 0.5 = 499000, my sd =$\sqrt {np*(1-p)}$= $\sqrt {998000*0.5*(1-0.5)}$, then apply CLT, my new sd = $\frac{sd}{\sqrt{998000}}$, and X = $\frac{1000000}{2}$+1-2000 = 498001. Then apply normal distribution. Am I right?

Comment: Seems quit good. However, I don't understand your last equation for $X$. What does $X$ represent? Is this the random variable that should converge to a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distributed variable for $n\to\infty$?

Comment: To win this election, candidate A has to get ar least 500001 votes to win , and he has already got 2000 votes. Therefore it's the formula above. But my z-score is pretty large, which gives me probability equals 1. I think I may wrong in some steps.

Comment: The standard deviation is about $500$, so $A's$ loss would be a $4\sigma$ event...very unlikely indeed.